# Fill array of objects with multiple keys and values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a method on @change which recieve these values.

```
 changeAttr(id, key, value) {
  const selections = [];
},
```

> **id** could be any number, **key** could be: color, size, sex, etc..., **value** could be: red, 8, female, etc. In the first reception the values can be for example: `id = 3`, `key = "color"`, `value = "red"` and they change when the user select another option. For example:   `id = 3`, `key = "sex"`, `value = "female"` or  `id = 5`, `key = "size"`, `value = "50"` ...etc

I want to dynamically fill an array of objects with the values this way for example.

```
selections = [{
              "3": { 
                  "color": "red",
                  "sex": "male",
                  "size": "40" 
              },
              {
              "5": { 
                  "color": "black",
                  "sex": "female",
                  "size": "36" 
              },
              {
              "8":{ 
                 "color": "black",
                 "sex": "female",
                 "size": "36" 
              ...
              },
              ...
              }];
```

I want to overwrite the values ​​if the key already exists for the same id. If it does not exist, it must be added for its id.

I hope I have explained clearly. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use an array syntax :

Considering

```
let yourObject = {}
```

You can use [] to define a property

```
yourObject["color"] = "red"
```

So with your logic, you can do :

```
yourObject[key] = value
```

Tip :
Using int strings as index is not really a good pratice because JS reindexes arrays, i advise you to construct your object like this :

```js
[
  {
    id: 3
    color: "red",
    sex: "male",
    size: "40" 
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    color: "black",
    sex: "female",
    size: "36" 
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    color: "black",
    sex: "female",
    size: "36" 
  },
  ...
];
```

EDIT :

```js
const selections = [];

function changeAttr(id, key, value) {
   
  // Get the index in selection by id
  let index = selections.map(t=>t.id).indexOf(id)
  
  
  if (index !== - 1) { // if the id have been found
  
      selections[index][key] = value // It create the index "key" if not found, and replace the value if found 
  
  } else { // if the id have not been found
    
    let tmp = {
      id: id
    }
    
    tmp[key] = value
    selections.push(tmp)
    
  } 
}

console.log(selections)
changeAttr(6, "color", "red")
console.log(selections)
changeAttr(3, "sex", "female")
console.log(selections)
changeAttr(6, "sex", "male")
console.log(selections)
changeAttr(6, "color", "yellow")
console.log(selections)
```

You can run snippet to see, I think that is what you are looking for

Comment: thanks for your contribution. I still have doubts how to build the array depending on the inputs and overwrite if the key already exists for the same id :(

Comment: I've edited my answer, and i think this is more explicit

Answer (score 0):

```
newValue =  { 
  "color": "black",
  "sex": "female",
  "size": "36" 
 }


selections.forEach((oItem)=>{
  for(let key in oItem){
    if(oItem.hasOwnProterty(key)){
       // overwrite
    }else {
    // set the newValue 
    }

  }
  
})
```

Comment: thanks! I need some help with the newValue setting too. I mean, I  need to group the values by id too.

Comment: if I helped you pls mark my answer as the correct one :)

Comment: Of course, I will do it if a get this thing clear. I still have doubts to resolve. sorry :(